# ORA-06550 : Oracle SqlPlus

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare
doesExists number:=0;
begin
select count(1) into doesExists from tab where tname = 'EOSS2G_GREEN_RLDEP';
if doesExists = 1 
then
    execute immediate 'drop table EOSS2G_GREEN_RLDEP';
    --execute immediate 'create table EOSS2G_GREEN_RLDEP as select * from EOSS2G_RLDEP';
else
    execute immediate 'create table EOSS2G_GREEN_RLDEP as select * from EOSS2G_RLDEP';
end if;
end;
/
```

The Error Message I am getting is :

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

& = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
<> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
Position: 28, Line: 2, Column: 21
SQL: declare
doesExists number:=0
^-- error here -- ORA-06550: line 2, column 21:
```

I have looked into varied solutions online but still they did not help solve the issue.

Can somebody help me resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this particular error is not because of Database but with the platform through which I am working on. 
I have to explicitly specify sql block separator in the platform in order to commit the above statements.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this problem we found that there was an extra character (I think a ^Z) on the last line after the '/'. Once that was removed, the block ran fine for me. The DBA found the issue, but I don't recall what software he was using that showed him the character.

You might try deleting every line after the / and see if that helps.